# C++ How to optimize this algorithm ? (std::map)

Tags: c++, c++14

The problem is the following: We are given a number 's', s ∈ [0, 10^6], and a number 'n', n ∈ [0, 50000], then n numbers, and we have to find how many number pairs' sum is equal to the 's' number (and we must use either maps or sets to solve it)

Here is the example:

Input:

```
5 (this is s)
6 (this is n)
1 
4 
3 
6 
-1 
5
```

Output:

```
2
```

explanation : these are the  (1,4) and (6,−1) pairs. (1 +4 = 5 and 6 + (-1) = 5)

Here is my "solution" , I don't even know if it's correct, but it works for the example that we got.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin.tie(0);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    int s;
    cin >> s;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    map<int, int> numbers;

    int element;
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        cin >> element;
        numbers.insert(pair<int, int>(element, s-element));

    }
    for(map<int, int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); it++)
    {
        map<int, int>::iterator it2 = it;
        while(it2 != numbers.end())
        {
            if(it->second == it2->first)
            {
                counter++;
                break;
            }
            it2++;

        }
    }
    cout << counter << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the answers in advance! I'm still a beginner and I'm learning, sorry.

Comment: forgot to add: the maximum time allowed is 0.11 seconds, and my solution is slower than that  when I run it on the test site. So, if the method of solving it is correct, how could I make it faster and more efficient?

Comment: Maybe try `std::unordered_map`, it has average `O(1)` lookup - it's a hash map. Also feel free to edit your own questions in the future to add more information.

Comment: Nevermind, the second for loop is O(n^2) and totally unnecessary, you can just check for presence of `element, s-element` instead of inserting.

Comment: Use `std::map::find` instead of the inner loop. When you nail it with inputs that don't have duplicates, think how you would handle duplicates.

Comment: @Quimby so I can completely remove the second for loop and while loop, and solve it using the first for loop only?

Comment: @MassSpectrometer Well, yea. At that point you can check whether you have seen `s-e`, if so, you've a new duplicate pair.

Comment: @Quimby Thank you, it works now! Your solution is perfect, I will try to understand it now  and learn.

Comment: @MassSpectrometer No problem, yea, maybe try to step through a small example with paper and pencil.

Answer (score 0):

`element, s-element` is a good idea but there is no reason to store all the pairs and only then check for duplicates. This removes the `O(n^2)` loop you have there at the end.

The standard way using hashing would be:

```
seen=unordered_map<number,count>() 
for 1...n:
  e = read_int()
  if (s-e) in seen:
    duplicates+=seen[s-e] # Found new seen[s-e] duplicates.
  if e in seen:
    seen[e]+=1
  else:
    seen.insert(e,1)

return duplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute-force method, using a vector:

```
int target_s = 0;
int quantity_numbers = 0;
std::cin >> target_s >> quantity_numbers;
std::vector<int> data(quantity_numbers);
for (int i = 0; i < quantity_numbers; ++i)
{
    cin >> data[i];
}

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < quantity_numbers; ++i)
{
    for (j = 0; j < quantity_numbers; ++j)
    {
        if (i == j) continue;
        int pair_sum = data[i] + data[j];
        if (pair_sum == target_s) ++count;
    }
}
std::cout << count;
```

The above code includes the cases where pair <a,b> == s and pair <b,a> == s.  Not sure if the requirement only wants pair <a,b> in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As always with this kind of questions, the selection of the appropriate algorithm will improve your solution. Writing some "better" C++ code, will nearly never help. Also, brute forcing is nearly never a solution for such an algorithm.

With the following described approach (which was of course not invented by me), we need just one `std::map` (or even better, a `std::unordered_map`) and one for loop. We do not need to store the read values in an additional `std::vector` or such alike. So, we can come up with low memory condumption and fast computation.

Approach. Any time, after reading a value, we will calculate the delta from the desired sum.

If we look at the required condition that the current value and some previuosly read value, should add up to the desired sum, we can write the following mathematical equations:

```
currentValue + previouslyReadValue = desiredSum 
   or
desiredSum - currentValue =  previouslyReadValue
   or with
delta = desiredSum - currentValue
   -->
delta == previouslyReadValue
```

So, we need to look at the already read values and if they are equal to the delta (Because then they would add up the the desired sum), add their count of occurence the the resulting count of valid pairs.

The already read values and their count of occurence will be stored in a `std::unordered_map`.

All this will result in a 10 line solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    // Initialize our working variables
    int numberOfValues{}, desiredSum{}, currentValue{}, resultingCount{};

    // Read basic parameters. Desired sum and overall number of input values.
    std::cin >> desiredSum >> numberOfValues;

    // Here, we will store all values and their count of occurence
    std::unordered_map<int, int> valuesAndCount{};

    // Read all values and operate on them
    for (int i{}; i < numberOfValues; ++i) {

        std::cin >> currentValue;                       // Read from cin
        const int delta{ desiredSum - currentValue };   // Calculate the delta from the desired sum

        // Look, if the calculated delta is already in the map. Becuase, if the delta and the
        // current value sum up to our desired sum, then we found a valid pair.
        if (valuesAndCount.find(delta) != valuesAndCount.end())

            // Increase the resulting count, by the number of times that this delta value has already been there
            resultingCount += valuesAndCount[delta];

        // Nothing special, Just cound the occurence of this value.
        valuesAndCount[currentValue]++;
    }
    return !!(std::cout << resultingCount);
}
```